# Custom dijit not working after dojo upgrade

Tags: inheritance, upgrade, dojo, amd

I have created a simple dijit, that adds some validation options to TextBox dijit. You can see the code here:

http://dojo.pythonista.net/anthrax/js/AnthraxTextBox.js

This worked in dojo 1.7 and 1.8. However after upgrading to 1.9 it broke. The problem is I don't get any error message. When I try to require() this module like:

```
require(
    ['dojo/parser', ...some-modules, 'anthrax/js/AnthraxTextBox', ... some modules],
    function (parser) {
        console.log('parsing...');
        parser.parse();
    });
```

the above function isn't even called. But it fails completely silently. If I remove 'anthrax/js/AnthraxTextBox' from requirements - it gets called, but of course parser fails when it sees widgets declared as anthrax.AnthraxTextBox.

What is wrong with this widget or with the AMD I created that I can't require it?

Answer (score 1):

Try using define ( like in the link you posted ) instead of require.

Comment: I'm sorry - my dojo installation was broken for some reason. After reinstalling 1.9 it works.